# How to use auto layout on IOS8 Keyboard extension

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6, ios8-extension

Trying to make auto layout work with the keyboard extension. Initially i thought i will make the buttons programmatically but then i realized its better to do it with a xib because of my requirement and multiple screen sizes.

Please see the screenshot below on the current configuration i have made.
Button 2:
[image]

Button 1 and issue on the app:
[image]

All the constraints configuration looks like this:
[image]

All i am trying to do here is to make sure the button fills up the screen width. They can expand in width to match screen sizes and orientations. Somehow i feel that its not able to understand the device width. Do i need to specify something for that?

Thanks

Comment: Any help guys! Is this not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to set the *UIView's* dimensions on *viewDidLoad* so that it looks like something like this:

```
self.mainView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

I had the same problem and this did the trick for me. Your constraints are just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a constraint on the distance between the two buttons. Try adding on constraint between the buttons for each button.

Comment: What is the width constraint on Button 1? I see Button 2 has one, but it is currently disabled.

Comment: There is no width constraint on any of the button as i want them to stretch based on the layout. The ones in grey are deleted already.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Flores answer did the trick for me, too, but I had to put my code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Otherwise my keyboard would crash and not show up. Swift 3 Version:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let frameSize = self.view.frame.size
    self.mainView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)
}
```